# Does the Mac OS X SSH client integrate with other systems?

Tags: linux, macos, networking, ssh

I have MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), when I enable the SSH from (“Preferences - > Sharing”) it gives me link like this :

```
members-12-13.hallsnetwork.xxxx.com
```

Well, clearly the link is descriptive (not an IP address), does that mean Linux servers afford this feature to have certain configuration for the SSH links or what (to make them as part of the domain)?

Note that I am connected to a network in large institute.

Comment: `members-12-13.hallsnetwork.xxxx.com` looks like a hostname.

Comment: It is a host name, however it changes regularly (the numbers 12-13), and either I'm connected using the WiFi or the ethernet

Answer (score 0):

SSH does not integrate with other systems by default. Normally it will just open up port 22 on your local computer and allow SSH clients to connect to it. `members-12-13.hallsnetwork.xxxx.com` is most likely the reverse-DNS for your IP address.

Try finding your IP address using `ifconfig` and enter it [here](http://remote.12dt.com/). I would bet that it will give you the same hostname.

Comment: He said that he is on a network for a large institution. They often don't use NATed addresses but give publicly available ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I am connected to a network in large institute.

That’s exactly it. SSH does not have anything to do with this—and does not blindly integrate with a large network when it’s enabled—but rather the fact that your IP address has a hostname connected to it within your institute’s network. When you enable “Remote Login” a message—that reads something like this—would show up in the control panel:

> To log in to this computer remotely, type "ssh
>   username@members-12-13.hallsnetwork.xxxx.com".

That message is 100% auto-generated by the system and just there as a for convenience for you. You could just as easily remote into your system by using the raw IP address like this; note that `123.456.789.0` is not real and I am just using it for example’s sake:

```
ssh username@123.456.789.0
```

That said, fairly confident that the reverse DNS info on the hostname you are getting comes from [`arp` (Address Resolution Protocol)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/arp.4.html) traffic/data. So you can see similar info by typing in this [`arp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/arp.8.html) command from the command line in the “Terminal.”:

```
arp -a
```

That will list all the Internet-to-Ethernet address translation tables used by the address resolution protocol on your system. So the output of that would be something like this:

```
members-12-13.hallsnetwork.xxxx.com (123.456.789.0) at 11:ee:dd:ff:aa:cc on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```